# Updating parent and Child Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, parent-child

If I have a Parent and Child table , each time I modify that entry from Front End  I delete the data in the child table and inserts again. I'm doing this for years but wondering now is it a right method or is there any better methods ? .

Comment: seems like the right way because you do that when you have a column in both tables referencing the same column.

Comment: this is a too open question, it does not mean right/wrong unless we know your process flow. But if you already did that for years and no one complaint then indirectly prove it's right.

Comment: yes harry. I was also thought that was right way.  Today I was working on building audit trial for my DB .For Parent table I could track old and new values for a particular record easily . But for child tables I don't know what I do because each time it gets deleted and inserts again . So Audit table will store child data even if no change actually occurred in child data

Comment: I would suggest that deleting/re-inserting is not the right way, whether people have complained or not...unless I misunderstood your question.   The audit trail you want to implement is one good example--an insert is a "new record", not an Update--which should also be in the audit table.   How you implement the audit table is beyond the scope of this question but either way, you need to differentiate between inserts/updates/deletes.

Answer (score 1):

As Far as my knowledge deleting parent and child records is not a good practice, you can use either on of follow

Option 1

Transfer Old Record to another table which has same structure of original table

Option 2

Add a bit columns (eg: Inactive default value “FALSE”) to both child and parent tables before insert     new record, update old record as Inactive, but if you are going to use this method there will be modification in your program logic

Hope this will helps for you....